# ¿Como ejecutar un job desde otro jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jobs

He estado investigando y no doy con la tecla:

Tengo dos maquinas, cada una con un Jenkins configurado para lanzar unos jobs que actualizan los servidores alojados en esas dos maquinas.

Me gustaría crear en una tercera maquina un Jenkins para poder lanzar los jobs de los otros Jenkins y dejarlo todo configurado para que en el nuevo Jenkins tenga un job que lance todos los demás.

He hecho diferentes pruebas y no hay manera, seguramente se me escape algo. Gracias y un saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación oficial de jenkins puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters \
--user USER:TOKEN \
--data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"},`{"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
```

Donde:

> JENKIS_URL: es la IP:PUERTO donde tienes corriendo jenkins.
>
> JOB_NAME: es el nombre del job que quieres ejecutar.
>
> USER: usuario para logearse.
>
> TOKEN: token generado por usuario, lo generas en configuraciones de usuario. Ver el siguiente enlace: [ver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466090/how-to-get-the-api-token-for-jenkins)
> json: Aquí puedes pasar parámetros para el job que quieres ejecutar

La página oficial donde puedes encontrar más detalles es la siguiente: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Answer (score 0):

Bajate job import plugin desde Jenkins>Manage jenkins>Manage pligins, Con el puedes importarte los trabajos de otros jenkins.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/307628)

Comment: Hola David, ya he revisado y modificado la respuesta, gracias por la guia!